# Swap out page list controller in Concrete5

Tags: controller, swap, concrete5

In Concrete5 it is possible to overwride core code. This seems not to be the case for the PageList class. I believe this is because it is not part of the app container and is directly called in the code via the alias or full class new \Concrete\Core\Page\PageList();

Core::bind does not work

```
\Core::bind('\Concrete\Core\Page\PageList', function ($app, $params) {
return new \Concrete\Package\MyPackage\Src\Page\PageList();
});
```

Overwriting the alias is also not going to work. This is because in the core the alias and full class name are both used.

```
'aliases' => array(
    'PageList' => 'Concrete\Package\ZuiderlichtUtilities\Src\Page\PageList',
),
```

Is there an other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you specified what you are trying to accomplish, but if you wanted to completely override the pagelist block sitewide you would copy the controller.php and view.php from **concrete/blocks/page_list/** to **application/blocks/page_list/**

In most cases though, you would template it in **application/blocks/page_list/templates/** or extend it.

See: [Searching and Sorting with the PageList Object](http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-pages/searching-and-sorting-with-the-pagelist-object)